# Validación al guardar con entity framework Core

Tags: entity-framework

tengo una pregunta para ver si me pueden ayudar, tengo una restricción de solo permitir una cantidad de inscripciones en un sistema de cursos, como puedo hacerlo para si ya llegó al cupo permitido no permita la inscripción, cual sería la manera más adecuada de hacer esto, uso entity framework core para manejar la data, saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: Con Entity Framework cuenta cuantos registros tienes, dependiendo de eso, decides si permitir agregar uno nuevo, o no.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.